# What are the names of these variations on the transpose of a matrix and symmetric matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, terminology

Is there a name for the operator that reflects a matrix over the diagonal running from the top-right to the bottom-left? For the moment, define this reflection of a matrix $A$ as $A^*$. Is there a name for the family of matrices such that $A = A^*$? For example, let
$$
A =
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -1 & -1 & 1\\
0 & 1 & 0 & -1\\
0 & 0 & 1 & -1\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that such a matrix is said to be *persymmetric*.